# What is "bounds-checked" in WebAssembly Table?

Tags: webassembly

What is "bounds-checked" in WebAssembly Table?

And what's the difference between the "bounds-checked" process proceeding in linear memory and table?

Answer (score 2):

When you access a table with a non-existing index you get a trap. Analogous to memories, just that one addresses by table slot number and the other by byte offset.